# https://registry.gitlab.com/v2/: x509: certificate signed by unknown authority

Tags: docker, gitlab

Using a runner on a fresh Debian machine, when a job tries to connect to officiel Gitlab registry, I catch this error :

```
Get https://registry.gitlab.com/v2/: x509: certificate signed by unknown authority
```

I don't understand why, their certificat is an official one, valid.

So I tried to change config of my runner:

```
  [runners.docker]
    tls_verify = false
    image = "alpine:latest"
    privileged = false
    disable_entrypoint_overwrite = false
    oom_kill_disable = false
    disable_cache = false
    volumes = ["/cache"]
    shm_size = 0
```

And even add this to `/etc/docker/daemon.json`:

```
{
    "insecure-registries" : [ "registry.gitlab.com" ]
}
```

But still the error (I rebooted both docker & Gitlab runner container)